# Doctrine2: related keys

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have following table (type, id, title).

When new object is created and type=1 id should be 1, next object with type=1 id=2... But when I create object with type=2 id should be 1.

How can I do it with Doctrine2 and Symfony2?

Comment: Your meaning isn't very clear to me. Are you dealing with two separate entities and trying to store them in the same table? If so, why?

Comment: No, it's one entity. 'type' is category, and in each category id should incr. independent from others.

Comment: You can't do this in the same table if id is a primary key. I suppose you could have a category_id field and build it programmatically for each category, but as far as I know, Doctrine won't support this out of the box.

Comment: id is example field name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other have said, Doctrine 2 does not do this out of the box. The common practice is to make the ID field auto increment and a primary key in which case this is not possible. Primary keys must be unique.

With that said, a solution could be to use the entity manage to find the maximum value of ID where the type is the selected type and incrementing that value by 1.

For example:

```
// Retrieve the current maximum ID for the selected type
$id = $em->createQuery("SELECT MAX(e.id) AS id FROM Entities\entity e WHERE e.type = ?1")
  ->setParameter(1, $type)
  ->getSingleScalarResult();

// Set your current entity's ID
$entity->setId(++$id);

// Save the entity
...
```

Comment: What about concurrency? What happens when two requests try to create an entity at the same time and they both "select max" and get the same id, thus creating two entities with the same id (unless you set a unique attribute, which would throw an exception on insert anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using `MAX(id)` is not a very best solution as it might cause a few problems. What happen if you delete the newest record in given category and then add a new one? It will have the very same ID as previous had.

1. Composite primary keys (`type`, `id`) are not very well handled by Doctrine so far, so I suggest to create a classical primary key: integer, auto-increment key (at least for Doctrine's use). In addition you can always have a unique index on `type` and `type_id` columns and use it whenever you want.
2. Create your own implementation for auto-increment of `type_id` column:

   1. As `type_id` is associated with *Type* you could store additional column in `type` table: `next_auto_increment`, which stores a value that will be used for next record.
   2. Whenever you create a new record in your table simply select value for it's `type_id` from `type` table:

      ```
      $type = ...;

      $entity = new Entity();
      $entity->setType($type);
      $entity->setTypeId($type->getNextAutoIncrement()); 
      // btw: typeId is not a very best name

      $em->persist($entity);
      ```
   3. You will also need a trigger in your database to increment a value of `next_auto_increment` every time you insert a record (MySQL example):

      ```
      DELIMITER $$
      CREATE TRIGGER increment_ai AFTER insert ON entity_table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
          UPDATE type_table 
          SET next_auto_increment = next_auto_increment + 1 
          WHERE id = NEW.type;
      END$$
      DELIMITER ;
      ```

Answer (score 1):

As my comments above indicate, I don't think there's direct support for what you're trying to do out of the box. However, I think you should be able to approximate it with [class table inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), where each of your `type` categories is its own entity that shares common data on the class table and keeps track of its own indexing.

Comment: I can't use table inheritance because they should create dynamically.